# How to perform these joins with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Having these tables:

```
clients
-------------------
id
name
town

companies
------------------
id
name

credits
------------------
clients_id
companies_id
credit
```

Example:

```
clients
-------------
1  john doe   London
2  jane smith Paris

companies
-------------
1  mycompany1
2  mycompany2

credits
-------------
1  1   5000
1  2   3250
2  2   4500
```

How can I list all the clients including an additional column for each credit she has in a company? I also need to alias each of these columns in this fashion: "credit_"

Something like:

```
id  name        town    credit_1  credit_2
1   john doe    London  5000      3250
2   jane smith  Paris   NULL      4500
```

I'm not sure if doing two LEFT JOINS to credits would work.

Comment: And what have you tried?  You must have at least a partial solution.

Comment: What's the expected result if john doe suddenly gets another credit?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'm totally lost about this. Nothing I've done gets close to what I need.

Comment: That's call to _pivot_ a table. You should do a search on this term.

Comment: @jarlh One client can only have a unique credit from a company. He couldn't have more credits in the example, just an update in the ones he has.

Comment: Generally you are looking for PIVOT in MySQL. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: Wow, looks kind of complex that PIVOT solution even though the problem seemed easy to tackle at first. Thank you!